# Espresso: Verify if one or more listView items contains an item with a substring

Tags: android-espresso

I have to verify that a substring inside one itemm is contained within a list view.  The problem is, if more than one item contains this substring -  an ***matching*** error is thrown.

Is there a clean espresso way to take the first item matched like in Robotium?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should take a look at withChild and withParent methods.

something like this:

```
onView(allOf(withText("your_substring"), withParent(withId(R.id.element_id_here))));
```

that should work.